# Validate "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" during springboot startup

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Is there a way to validate the "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" property during application startup to ensure that it's set only to none? I want to force all deployments(including dev) to use liquibase.

Edit :- I also need to ensure that this property is not accidentally set in production, which could wipe out the data.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you can maintain a universal application.properties/yml file and set the property (`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`) there. Afterwards, maintain a separate property/yml file (`application_*.properties/yml`) which will fetch the properties from application.properties/yml file, by default. 
Also, you can maintain other "common" properties in the parent file.

Comment: My requirement is also to ensure that somebody accidentally doesn't set a property in production. It could still happen with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up on starting of your application by implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` class, like:

```
@Component
public class YourListner implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String hibernateDdlAuto;


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        if (!"none".equalsIgnoreCase(hibernateDdlAuto))
            throw new MyValidationException();

    }
}
```

Moreover, you can even make it more verbose by registering your own [FailureAnalyzer.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/diagnostics/FailureAnalyzer.html)

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the validation is done only after the app is initialized. By the time we get here, the damage(i.e. recreating tables) would already be done.